# Java StringBuilder - appending characters

Tags: java, netbeans, append, stringbuilder

I have a hangmanframe, welcomeframe, and a mainframe, and I would like to append stars (*) on the mainframe when you win a hangman game

HangmanFrame:

```
public void win(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats! The word was " + GuessWord);
    MainFrame.totalStars.append("*");
    MainFrame.totalLabel.setText(MainFrame.stars);
    setVisible(false);
    MainFrame.hangmanButton.setEnabled(false);
    MainFrame.returnMain();
}
```

MainFrame:

```
    public static final StringBuilder totalStars = new StringBuilder();
    public static String stars = totalStars.toString();

    public static void returnMain(){
            totalStars.append("* ");
            totalLabel.setText(stars);
            WelcomeFrame.playButton.doClick();
    }
```

WelcomeFrame:

```
    private void playButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String userName = nameText.getText();

    // Open MainFrame
    MainFrame MFrame = new MainFrame();
    MFrame.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
    MainFrame.welcomeLabel.setText("Welcome " + userName + "!");
    MainFrame.totalStars.append("* ");
    MainFrame.totalStarsLabel.setText(MainFrame.stars);
    }
```

I have a label (totalLabel) that I would like to add stars (*) to. But when the method runs in the HangmanFrame, it goes to the PlayFrame but doesn't add on any stars whatsoever.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**SOLVED:**

changed method name to returnMain()

changed all instances of "stars" with "totalStars.toString()"

Comment: This code would not even compile: "return" is a keyword and cannot be used as the name of a method in your MainFrame listing. On another subject, I would recommend to follow good OOP practices and properly encapsulate fields in getter/setter methods.

Comment: i changed the method to read `returnMain()`, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your program will not compile because of `public static void return() {...`, I think you should know that `return` is a *reserved word* in Java.

Second, You make `public static String stars = totalStars.toString();` and that is OK, however
it doesn't mean that `stars` will always contain what `totalString` has. It is just instantaneous.

You should definitely use `totalLabel.setText(totalStars.toString());`

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but it makes multiple stars, i just want one?

Comment: @CodeAddict upvote my answer then =) if you want one asterisk, append one asterisk, not more.

Comment: okay, so when you win the hangman game the code reads `MainFrame.totalStars.append("*");` why is it doing it more than once if this code is only read once?

Comment: @CodeAddict if you are clicking the button many times, it will append more.

Comment: I had the append method in lots of places apparently, just took all but one out and it works. Thanks! accpeted as answer